# How to use Angular 4 in 2018, when Angular 5 has become the current version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I would like to use angular 4 with @angular/cli.

1. Checked available vesions before installing: npm view @angular/cli versions
2. Installed CLI 1.6.8 because it looks like that this version should be latest patch of Angular 4:
3. npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8
4. ng -v output shows this:

Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 6.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10

Did I actually install Angular 5? How can I get Angular 4?

Comment: Modify package.json file and set angular version to 4

Comment: @David I am by no means an Angular expert.. Could you elaborate or point to a sample? This file in the AppData or the current project file? 
 C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json

Comment: On your project root.

Comment: Thanks David! Rukshan's answer got me on the right track. Wish I knew why the question was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you create the angular project using Agular Cli there will be a package.json file in the root of the project.

In there you can find "**dependencies**" & "**devDependencies**" sections with required angular and other module versions. You can change those to versions you want and run

```
npm install
```

Have a look at [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for more details about the package.json

Also there is an nice [tool](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) to see which versions combination you want to run specific angular version. Play around with it find other dependencies you want.

**Update**

Another thing that you can try is this:

```
> npm remove -g @angular/cli
> npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10
> ng --version
  @angular/cli: 1.4.10
> ng new myangular4
```

It creates below package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myangular4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },...
```

In @angular/cli: 1.4.10 it will genarate angular 4 app. So I believe better approach is this other than messing around with dev/dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the tool! I downgraded npm "npm install -g npm@3.10.10" ... Is the next step to match all Angular 4 dependencies listed here:??
 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.7/package.json

Comment: I updated the answer. Please have a look and if this is the answer you were looking please mark it as accepted :)